# Map column data to a value (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, dictionary

I have an Oracle database and I have a table named `Car`. I can select the `Mileage` of the cars like this:

`SELECT MILEAGE FROM CAR`

This gives me:

- 100
- 500
- 1000
- etc.

However, I would like that values above 1000 are labeled as `High` and the rest as `Low`, like this:

- Low
- Low
- High
- Low

How do I need to change my initial query to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN MILEAGE > 1000 THEN 'High'
  ELSE 'Low'
  END
FROM CAR
```

Comment: I *knew* it had to be something simple, I just couldn't figure out what, thanks!