# Oracle - Map column data to a value

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me first point out that my question is going to be very very close to this question: [map-column-data-to-a-value-oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248392/map-column-data-to-a-value-oracle)

Please quickly read that one first.

Now in my case I need the exact same thing but not as the primary query. Instead I need the information as one part of my query.

I have this table:

```
someId | someValue | dataType
   1   |    500    | 1
   2   | someValue | 2
```

And I know that dataType "1" means "Integer". I also know the meaning of the other values in the dataType column.

So I want to select all entries in the table but have their dataTypes as their human readable values instead of their numbers:

Results:

```
1, 500, Integer
2, someString, String
```

Trying to apply the solution of the question I linked, I created a subquery like

```
SELECT
someId,
someValue,
(
  SELECT CASE
  WHEN dataType = 1 THEN 'INTEGER'
  WHEN dataType = 2 THEN 'FLOAT'
  WHEN dataType = 3 THEN 'TEXT'
  ELSE 'DATE'
END
  myTable
) as myDataType
```

I will get a subquery that returns more than 1 result and Oracle will complain.

Since I access the DB through SQL directly, I need a "pure SQL" solution. Otherwise I could just parse the value through a mapping, in say PHP. But that's not possible here. I am shooting some queries at a DB to try and gather information about the data and structure, which we don't know about. So only SQL is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT someId,
       someValue,
       CASE
          WHEN dataType = 1 THEN 'INTEGER'
          WHEN dataType = 2 THEN 'FLOAT'
          WHEN dataType = 3 THEN 'TEXT'
          ELSE 'DATE'
       END as Datatype
from  myTable
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!